# Android AsyncTask Bad Actors

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Scoured the net for answers although perhaps I'm using the wrong search terms...

What process in Android makes it so that the AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR variable is per app? Does it have to do with the Zygote forking on Android?

I can see why Google did it this way (to prevent malicious apps from clogging up the Thread Pool Executor with long running tasks), but looking at the code the AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR variable is a public static variable that is available to all apps from the operating system.

Comment: Every app runs in a separate process with it's own runtime.

Comment: So what is actually shared/copied between apps when they fork the main zygote process? Is it only the core Dalvic runtime code that are copied over and nothing else?

Comment: I don't know entirely, but I think certain Android system resources (layouts, drawables, those kinds of resources), so those are basically pre-loaded for your process. But I know for certain that your app and my app are not sharing the same `AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR`.